# How to access python library stored in separate environment?

Tags: python, error-handling, environment-variables, environment, pymatgen

For my project, I am using the Pymatgen libraries. I have installed it in a separate environment as "my_pymatgen". Now, during using the `import pymatgen` command it is giving the error `ModuleNotFoundError`.
How to access this library?

Comment: The whole *point* of virtual environments is that they shouldn't share libraries and import from each other ...

Comment: Insufficient data. For example, you don't define what you mean by separate environment". However, I am reasonably certain that the comment by @juanpa.arrivillaga is relevant. If you switch to the environment where your installed the Pymatgen module are you able to import it?